# I want to show Composable UI on top of dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I want display composable screens on top of dialog box.

Is it possible to show composable screen top of dialog box in android.

If it is possible please share your thoughts and how can I achieve that in Jetpack compose.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.